# How to add escape characters to a filename to be consumed later by a shell command?

Tags: python, bash, macos, ffmpeg

I am trying to find out which of my video files are corrupted. I loop through a directory, grab each video file, and check if it is corrupt/healthy. If the filename has no spaces nor special characters, it will work. Unfortunately, many of my files have spaces or parenthesis in the name, and this causes my shell command `ffmpeg` within my python script to fail. How can I retrieve the filenames in `abs_file_path` with the escape characters preceding the special characters?

**Example filename:** Movie Name (1080p)

**Goal:** Movie\ Name\ \(1080p\)

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(tuple(VIDEO_EXTENSIONS)):
        print(f'PROCESSING: {filename}...')

        abs_file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

        proc = subprocess.Popen(f'./ffmpeg -v error -i {abs_file_path} -f null - 2>&1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = proc.communicate()[0]

        row = ''
        if not output:
            # Healthy
            print("\033[92m{0}\033[00m".format("HEALTHY -> {}".format(filename)), end='\n')  # red
            row = [filename, 0]
        else:
            # Corrupt
            print("\033[31m{0}\033[00m".format("CORRUPTED -> {}".format(filename)), end='\n')  # red
            row = [filename, 1]

        results_file_writer.writerow(row)
        results_file.flush()

results_file.flush()
results_file.close()
```

Comment: The safest way to do this is with `shell=False` (and pass the command & args as a list, rather than a string). That avoids shell parsing entirely. You'd need to handle `stderr` explicitly, though, since the `2>&1` part only works in a shell.

Comment: does `re.escape` work for your purposes? from what I know the `//` displayed by it is still equivalent to `/` when it is actually being processed. If that doesn't work, would encasing the `abs_file_path` in single/double quotes work instead?

Comment: @Shorn `re.escape` is not the right choice here. e.g. it'll not escape spaces.

Comment: @pynexj my test of `re.escape` does show it escaping spaces, but perhaps its a version specific difference.

Comment: @Shorn aha. i did not try it at all since by definition SPACE has no special meanings in regex. anyway im not sure if `re.escape` would always work for this purpose since it's not designed for this.

Comment: ok. see this example -- `re.escape("foo'bar")` (py 3.11.2) would give `foo'bar` which is not properly quoted for shell.

Comment: True, I don't work with shell commands often so I'm not as familiar with their intricacies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [shlex.quote()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) .

A simple example —

```py
# cat run.py
import shlex, subprocess

fname = 'Movie Name (1080p)'
shcmd = 'ls -l %s' % shlex.quote(fname)

print('shcmd:', shcmd)
subprocess.run(shcmd, shell=True)
```

```
# python3 run.py
shcmd: ls -l 'Movie Name (1080p)'
-rw-r--r--  1 pynexj  staff  0 Mar  9 09:55 Movie Name (1080p)
```

Comment: Solved:

`proc = subprocess.Popen(f'./ffmpeg -v error -i {shlex.quote(abs_file_path)} -f null - 2>&1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`